# How to use the <foreach> statement correctly in Mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

When I use the  statemant, there is always a problem,

```
Parameter 'item' not found.
```

And this is my sql statemant:

```
<select id="getTest" resultType="java.util.HashMap" parameterType="java.util.List">
    <![CDATA[
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS commentCount, WORK_ID AS workId FROM TB_COMMENT WHERE TB_COMMENT.WORK_ID IN
          <foreach item="item" collection="list" separator="," open="(" close=")" index="">
              #{item}
          </foreach>
         GROUP BY TB_COMMENT.WORK_ID
    ]]>
</select>
```

And this is my java statemant:

```
@MapKey("workId")
public Map<Integer, String> getTest(List<Integer> workIds)throws DataAccessException;
```

The implement:

```
@Resource
private StatusMapper statusMapper;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (WorkModel i : pictures)
     if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(i.getUserId()))
         list.add(Integer.parseInt(i.getUserId()));
Map<Integer,String> tset = statusMapper.getTest(list);
```

Any help is hopful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, It seems that in , the dynamic sql can't parse, and I remove them, it works. Thanks people who spends time here.

Comment: Sorry, in<![CDATA[ ]]>